# How do I test a util detect OS class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I create a class that detect the OS:

```
    public class OperatingSystemProvider {

    private final String osName;

    public OperatingSystemProvider(){
        this.osName = getOSName();
    }

    public boolean isWindowsOS(){
        return osName.contains("windows");
    }

    public boolean isLinuxOS(){
        return osName.contains("linux");
    }

    private String getOSName(){
        return System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

And I created a class to test this:

```
public class OperatingSystemTests {

    @Test
    public void IsWindowsSystemInWidowsSystemTest(){
        Assert.assertTrue(new OperatingSystemProvider().isWindowsOS());
    }

    @Test
    public void IsLinuxSystemInWidowsSystemTest(){
        Assert.assertFalse(new OperatingSystemProvider().isLinuxOS());
    }

    @Test
    public void IsWindowsSystemInLinuxSystemTest(){
        Assert.assertFalse(new OperatingSystemProvider().isWindowsOS());
    }

    @Test
    public void IsLinuxSystemInLinuxSystemTest(){
        Assert.assertTrue(new OperatingSystemProvider().isLinuxOS());
    }
}
```

The test 2 tests passed in Windows and 2 tests passed in Linux.

I don't want to mock the the getOSName method, because this can lead to wrong assumptions (I think). So how can I test this class to passed in all tests in independent of the system?

Comment: If you want to test if your code correctly identifies the OS it is running on you don't have another way then... run it on the corresponding OS. You can temporarily change the system property I guess but that's not getting you anywhere. In the end you want to test it in a real world scenario -> actually running on the OS you want to detect.

Comment: Also sure you could mock the return of the `System.getProperty` but what would that be good for? Checking if the single "return" line of your code is getting executed? I would consider that wasted resources on testing.

Comment: Also, sidenote: `System.getProperty` will return null if the property wasn't found which will lead to a NPE in your `getOSName()` method should that property actually not exist for some reason. Probably want to check that.

Comment: thank you for the tips, but my application is created to runs in Linux and Windows, so I need to detect the two systems.

Comment: If your application expected to work on different OS, then you need to run tests in different OS as well. So for testing this class you will have two tests which need to be run on Windows and two tests which need to be run on Linux

Comment: thank you Fabio, It's make sense to run tests in different OS. So to ignore the failed tests when run on Windows I'm using the EnabledOnOS feature from JUnit 5

Answer (score 1):

The tests need to be executed on the corresponding OS. That's the best way to assure the tests will behavior exactly what should be. So to run tests according OS, the JUnit 5 has a feature called [EnabledOnOS](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/EnabledOnOs.html)

```
@Test
@EnabledOnOs(WINDOWS)
public void IsLinuxSystemInWidowsSystemTest() {
    Assertions.assertFalse(new OperatingSystemProvider().isLinuxOS());
}
```

Comment: Now you need at least two different platforms to run your tests.